# ASP .Net MVC Routing without Controller and Action Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

simple question. I want something like:

http:/ /www.mywebsite.com/microsoft or http:/ /www .mywebsite.com/apple
so microsoft and apple should be like id but i use it just like controller in the default

this is the default route

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

This produce something like http:/ /www.mywebsite .com/home/aboutus or http: //www.mywebsite .com/products/detail/10

I added another route

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Partner", // Route name
            "{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Partners"}, // Parameter defaults
            new { id = @"\d+" }
        );
```

but this has constraint that only allow numeric id.

how do I accomplish what I wanted.

thanks

Answer (score 4):

If the expression can contain only letters and digits you could modify the constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Partner", // Route name
    "{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Partners"}, // Parameter defaults
    new { id = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$" }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to provide a numeric constraint, just delete the 4th parameter, ie

```
routes.MapRoute("Partner", "{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Partners"});
```

The 4th parameter is an anonymous object that provides constraints for the route parameters that you have defined.  The names of the anonymous object members correspond to the route parameters - in this case "controller" or "action" or "id", and the values of these members are **regular expressions** that constrain the values that the parameters must have in order to match the route.  "\d+" means that the id value must consist of one or more digits (only).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve but it looks like you need a custom route constraint. Take a look here for an example:

http://blogs.planetcloud.co.uk/mygreatdiscovery/post/Custom-route-constraint-to-validate-against-a-list.aspx

Remember to register the route constraint first